# Website won't load on one machine and on others it will

Tags: windows

I've been scraping a website for a few days, I scraped heaps! All of a sudden the site wouldn't load on the computer (times out) but will load on the other one I have (one internet wired router - so denifitely the issue is linked with the computer not the internet).

I can't access it using `python`, not even via `selenium` webdriver.

I am on Windows 10 if that matters.

Things I've done to resolve it:

1. Check if the site address appeard on the blocked list at `C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts` and it did not.
2. run `ping [website]` command on the cmd on both machines and gives the same correct output

Any ideas?

Comment: Did or can you try accessing it via a VPN service? If you are on Windows you can use this one: http://betternet.co/.

Comment: Wow! It worked :) You saved my life buddy. On a side note, it seems to load pages slower, is that true?

Comment: No problem! Would you like to mark the question as solved with my answer? That gives me some points :)

Comment: I'd love to but I dont have enough points (15) to do it. I am sorry. Btw. `On a side note, it seems to load pages slower, is that true? `

Comment: Yes, it can slow down your internet.

Comment: Acvtually I cant upvote, I'll definitelly make it as solved on your asnwer in a few mins when Im allowed to. So it seems to scraped website just blocked me?

Comment: Yes, if it works with VPN, the website is blocked.

Comment: Do you think I'll get a chance to find another workaround (other than VPN - because it's quite slow)?

Comment: You could try finding out where the website is blocked (by the government of your country, on your router, your firewall, your ISP).

Comment: You helped me a ton! It may be slow but is working again. Much obliged :)

Comment: I may have one more question if you don't mind. Why the website will load on the other machine? Is the same IP, isn't it?

Comment: If it will load on the same network then it is likely a problem on your pc. It may be due to firewall restrictions. Disable the VPN and your firewall (be careful, and turn it on again if you are done!). Then try loading the page.

Comment: I did the steps and the site wouln't load again.

Comment: I am sorry, then I don't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try accessing the website via a VPN service. If you are looking for a free one, take a look at:

> http://betternet.co/